# Invalidate Internal Page Cache on cookie change

Tags: caching, cookies

There's the `cookies` and `cookies:MY_COOKIE_NAME` cache context from [core](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.3.9/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/Context/CookiesCacheContext.php). Now I need to invalidate the Internal Page Cache for anonymous users when the value of a specific cookie changes. How can I implement this?

I tried to add:

```
$build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'cookies:MY_COOKIE_NAME'
```

in `hook_entity_build_defaults_alter`, but that doesn't help and the page still returns from the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the `PageCache::getCacheId` method by adding the cookie value to form the Cache ID.

Have a look at [Page Cache by cookies](https://cornel.co/article/drupal8/page-cache-cookies-or-anything-available-http-request) example.

Comment: The linked example works beautifully, and is well described (I had the same question as OP, and solved it using this pattern). I think it should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, this answer really saved me

Answer (score 3):

The *Internal Page Cache* doesn't support cache contexts. It is a simple reverse proxy designed to serve static database content and the only Drupal specific feature it has is to invalidate cache tags. For more dynamic use cases you have to uninstall this module.

The *Dynamic Page Cache* will then be the frontend cache for anonymous traffic. It is not as fast as the *Internal Page Cache*, though, so if it doesn't provide the performance you need consider a third-party reverse proxy which is able to handle cookies dynamically.

Comment: do you know any example of where a reverse proxy able to handle cookies has been implemented?

Comment: Normally a reverse proxy either filters a cookie or denies caching and you can configure this behavior. The Drupal built-in page cache does nothing of this.

Comment: Hmm,OK. The thing is that I have a custom entity type and I was expecting that only while viewing its page I can somehow create more cached versions of the page depending on the cookie.

Comment: If this is only for specific entity routes then you can add a no_cache route option, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2463533. This disables page caching entirely, though, also the dynamic page cache.

Comment: I found a way to implement it by extending `PageCache` class and I described it here https://cornel.co/article/drupal8/page-cache-cookies-or-anything-available-http-request